# Nodejs model is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implementing `caminteJs` on nodejs application, after define database schema on separated file i can't use that and i get this error:

```
TypeError: models.channels.create is not a constructor
```

i created models folder and in that i have some database schema which wrapped into separated file as

```
user.js //contains user table schema
news.js //contains news table schema
```

into `index.js` which its into models folder i have:

```
var users = require( './user' );
var news = require( './news' );

module.exports = {
    users:users,
    news:news
};
```

`user.js` file content:

```
var config = require('../config');
module.exports = function(schema){
    var users = config.define('users', {
         user_name: { type: schema.String, limit: 30 },
         ...
         created_at: { type: schema.Date },
         updated_at: { type: schema.Date }
    });

    return users;
};
```

`config.js` file content:

```
var caminte = require( 'caminte' ),
    Schema = caminte.Schema,
    config = {
        driver: "mysql",
        host: "localhost",
        port: "3306",
        username: "root",
        password: "",
        database: "test",
        pool: true
    },
    schema = new Schema( config.driver, config );

module.exports = {
    caminte: caminte,
    Schema: Schema,
    config: config,
    schema: schema
}
```

and then my `server.js` to use them:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' ),
    ...
    config = require( './config' ),
    models = require( './models' );

io.on( 'connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on( "new_user", function (data, device) {
        const channels = new models.users.create(function(err){
            user_name: 'Peter'
        });

        console.log( channels );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: @jfriend00 `models` is a folder which that have one `index.js` and some file as database schema i use require that to import all files,please see this part of my post as `into index.js which its into models folder i have:`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want and how your schema looks like but for creation try to use:

```
 const user = models.users.create(function(err){
            console.log('Error happened', err);
        });
```

Comment: You can either use `model.entity.create(errCallback)` or `new model.entity()` and `entity.save(callback)` but not the first option with `new`. See the edit.